# Why is my manually updated content not appearing up to date in Symfony/Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my Symfony web application (version 7), I am taking information hosted in a database.

I have updated a post directly in the database, running this query in console:

```
UPDATE `posts_xyz` 
    SET `post_content`='<p>New content ...</p>' 
WHERE ID=56;
```

But its content is not updated when I navigate to the corresponding URL.

This is my controller, the problem occurs in the method: `showByPostName()`

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Post;
use App\Repository\PostRepository;
use App\Entity\Subscribe;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'homepage')]
    public function index(PostRepository $postRepository): Response
    {
        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig');
    }

    #[Route('/{post_name}', name: 'post_name')]
    public function showByPostName(string $post_name, PostRepository $postRepository): Response
    {
        $post = $postRepository->findOneBy(['post_name' => $post_name, 'post_status'=>'publish', 'post_type'=>'page']);
        if (!$post) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'No encontrado '.$post_name
            );
        }
         return $this->render('post/index.html.twig', ['post' => $post]);
    }
}
```

This is my Entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\WpDcjqPostsRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: PostRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name:"xyz_posts")]

class Post
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
    private ?string $post_content = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
    private ?string $post_title = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 200)]
    private ?string $post_name = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 20)]
    private ?string $post_status = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 20)]
    private ?string $post_type = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
    private ?string $post_excerpt = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setID(int $id): self
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPostContent(): ?string
    {
        return $this->post_content;
    }

    public function setPostContent(string $post_content): self
    {
        $this->post_content = $post_content;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPostTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->post_title;
    }

    public function setPostExcerpt(string $post_excerpt): self
    {
        $this->post_excerpt = $post_excerpt;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setPostTitle(string $post_title): self
    {
        $this->post_title = $post_title;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPostName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->post_name;
    }

    public function getPostExcerpt(): ?string
    {
        return $this->post_excerpt;
    }

    public function setPostName(string $post_name): self
    {
        $this->post_name = $post_name;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

If I add `dd($post);` in the controller, I can see on screen:

```
HomeController.php on line 54:
App\Entity\Post {#699 ▼
  -id: 56
  -post_content: "<p>Old content ...</p>"
  -post_title: "***"
  -post_name: "***"
  -post_status: "publish"
  -post_type: "page"
  -post_excerpt: ""
```

If I execute this query in the console:

```
mysql > SELECT post_content FROM xyz_posts WHERE ID=56;
```

I can see:

```
post_content
-------------------------
<p>New content ... </p>
```

As you can see, the content is updated in the database table, but in the controller it is still showing the old content.

I have tried the following commands, to clear the Doctrine cache:

```
bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query --env=prod
bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-result --env=prod
bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata --env=prod
```

To clear the app cache, I have also tried:

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
```

and:

```
bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

I've also tried this:

```
php bin/console cache:pool:clear --all
```

With the following result:

```
 // Clearing all cache pools...                                                 

 // Clearing cache pool: cache.app                                              

 // Clearing cache pool: cache.system                                           

 // Clearing cache pool: cache.validator                                        

 // Clearing cache pool: cache.serializer                                       

 // Clearing cache pool: cache.property_info                                    

 // Clearing cache pool: cache.asset_mapper                                     

 // Clearing cache pool: cache.messenger.restart_workers_signal                 

 // Clearing cache pool: cache.validator_expression_language                    

 // Clearing cache pool: cache.doctrine.orm.default.result                      

 // Clearing cache pool: cache.doctrine.orm.default.query                       

 // Clearing cache pool: cache.security_expression_language                     

 // Clearing cache pool:                                                        
 // cache.security_is_granted_attribute_expression_language
```

But the problem persists.

What do I need to do to see my updated content?

Comment: "but its content is not updated" - what does that mean? You haven't shared any code that updates something. Did you check whether the data you want to read from the database is **really** stored there, for example through phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @NicoHaase I did the update **directly** in the database through a query. And I have verified that the content is up to date there. Below I make an edit to add that debugging.

Comment: @NicoHaase I have added new information in the question, I hope it is better explained now.

Comment: Did you check what Symfony's profiler has to tell about this? It should show the query that has been used, and whether any cache was involved. Also, it looks strange that you've used the text `<p>Here new content</p>` during the update and got `<p>New content ... </p>` when directly querying the database

Comment: @NicoHaase I have used `Old content...` and `New content...` to replace long content, for simplicity. It's a mistake in that substitution, sorry.

Comment: @NicoHaase the query is: `SELECT t0.ID AS ID_1, t0.post_content AS post_content_2, t0.post_title AS post_title_3, t0.post_name AS post_name_4, t0.post_status AS post_status_5, t0.post_type AS post_type_6, t0.post_excerpt AS post_excerpt_7 FROM xyz_posts t0 WHERE t0.post_name = '***' AND t0.post_status = 'publish' AND t0.post_type = 'page' LIMIT 1;`, and in the Profiler I don't see anything related to cache.

Comment: And this query looks like it should? Which results do you receive when putting the query into the MySQL shell?

Comment: @NicoHaase if I run that query in mysql shell I can see the new content, not the old.

Comment: @NicoHaase It was a rookie mistake: I had two different databases, both with a table `xyz_posts`. In the console I did the UPDATE to the database table other than the one I was connecting to in the application. Thank you very much for your help. I can see the error by checking in the Profiler.

Comment: Can you share your `doctrine.yaml` (or so) configuration, please?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE `posts_xyz` - In your sql you update table with name "posts_xyz", but in your entity you have different table name #[ORM\Table(name:"xyz_posts")]
Upd: I am little bit confused because in select query you have "xyz_posts" name of the table.